# Grouping classes in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a class called as Student, with three fields, I need to convert that class into a GroupedStudent. How can this be achieved?

```
var students: List<Student> = mutableListOf(Student("A", "X", 1), Student("A", "Y", 2), Student("B", "X", 2), Student("B", "Y", 2))
```

I need to convert the above list to a GroupedStudent List, how can i do that?

They should be grouped by studentName, and have the SubjectMarks as list.

```
class Student {
    var name: String
    var subject: String
    var marks: Int
}

class GroupedStudent {
    var name: String
    var subMarks: MutableList<SubjectMarks> 
}

class SubjectMarks {
    var subject: String
    var marks: Int
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `GroupedStudent`  contains a collection of `Student`s...

Comment: @Markoto They should be grouped by studentName, and have the SubjectMarks as list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Kotlin stdlib [Collections functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html#functions):

```
var students: List<Student> = mutableListOf(Student("A", "X", 1), Student("A", "Y", 2), Student("B", "X", 2), Student("B", "Y", 2))

val groupedMap = students.groupBy { it.name }
val groupedStudents = mutableListOf<GroupedStudent>()
groupedMap.forEach { key, value ->
    val groupedStudent = GroupedStudent(key, value.map { SubjectMarks(it.subject, it.marks) }.toMutableList())
    groupedStudents.add(groupedStudent)
}
```

This will result in a `List` of `GroupedStudent`, with each `GroupedStudent` containing a list of students' marks who have that name.

Answer (score 1):

If your Student class is correct, i.e. marks should be Int and not array or list of integers and you really want to convert it to "GroupedStudent List" you can use sortedWith and map methods:

```
class Student(var name: String, var subject: String, var marks: Int) {
  override fun toString(): String = "name: $name, subject: $subject, marks: $marks"
}

class GroupedStudent(var name: String, var subMarks: MutableList<SubjectMarks>) {
  override fun toString(): String = "name: $name, subject: $subMarks"
}

class SubjectMarks(var subject: String, var marks: Int) {
  override fun toString(): String = "subject name: $subject, marks: $marks"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val students: List<Student> = mutableListOf(Student("B", "Y", 2),
                                              Student("A", "X", 1),
                                              Student("B", "X", 2),
                                              Student("A", "Y", 2))

  val groupedStudents: List<GroupedStudent> = students.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.name }))
        .map { student -> GroupedStudent(student.name, mutableListOf(SubjectMarks(student.subject, student.marks))) }

  println(groupedStudents)
}
```

The [result](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/4ot3m17r00uggfv6ckm3c8on50/ufpvillo3oesukdenvs1imqh6e):

```
[name: A, subject: [subject name: X, marks: 1], name: A, subject: [subject name: Y, marks: 2], name: B, subject: [subject name: Y, marks: 2], name: B, subject: [subject name: X, marks: 2]]
```

**BUT** if you want to group your Student objects in a map with name as key and list of subject/marks as list of Pairs, you can use groupBy:

```
class Student(var name: String, var subject: String, var marks: Int) {
  override fun toString(): String = "name: $name, subject: $subject, marks: $marks"
}

class GroupedStudent(var name: String, var subMarks: MutableList<SubjectMarks>) {
  override fun toString(): String = "name: $name, subject: $subMarks"
}

class SubjectMarks(var subject: String, var marks: Int) {
  override fun toString(): String = "subject name: $subject, marks: $marks"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val students: List<Student> = mutableListOf(Student("B", "Y", 2),
                                          Student("A", "X", 1),
                                          Student("B", "X", 2),
                                          Student("A", "Y", 2))

  val groupedStudentsMap = mutableMapOf<String, List<Pair<String, Int>>>()
  students.groupBy { it.name }
        .forEach({ (key, value) -> 
          groupedStudentsMap[key] = value.map { element -> Pair(element.subject, element.marks) } })

  println(groupedStudentsMap)
}
```

The [result](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/u4qsm6ogpp0tg51onsm6ju91rq/7g4h1bg5ib596uk6jhjkt70jmk):

```
{B=[(Y, 2), (X, 2)], A=[(X, 1), (Y, 2)]}
```

Comment: This doesn't do any grouping.

Comment: Asker comments: "They should be grouped by studentName, and have the SubjectMarks as list."

Comment: @urgentx my bad, haven't read the comment. Thanks for pointing out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile now. Your student variable is inferred as a `Map.Entry`, not a `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the student's name and then do two simple mappings:

```
students.groupBy(Student::name).map { (name, students) ->
    GroupedStudent(name, students.map { SubjectMarks(it.subject, it.marks) }.toMutableList())
}
```